# Chrome Dev tool to find the origins of script

Tags: php, python, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently making a python program that will add a selected shoe from the Nike.com shoe store to the users cart.

This is my current test shoe: [air-jordan-4-retro--shoe Toddler](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/air-jordan-4-retro--shoe/pid-728188/pgid-728190)

So in chrome I press F12 to open the chrome Devtools and go into the elements tab. I know I am looking for a variable called skuId, which when using the find function in elements pops right up with the info I need. An example of this info is:

```
<option name="skuId" value="3108555:2C" data-label="(2C)">
           2C
        </option>
```

*That value of 3108555:2C represents the size of the shoe that I need, in this case "2C".*

However I have no clue on how to find out where that code originated from. It isn't in the source HTML so I assumed it would be in a linked file or generated by javascript/PHP but I am unable to find it. I was wondering if there was something with the devtools that would show where that code is, or if anyone would know how to get that information using urllib in python.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I would not recommend using this method if your future involves guessing.
In Chrome you can hit Ctrl+U that will give you the source of the webpage.
'view-source:http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/air-jordan-4-retro--shoe/pid-728188/pgid-728190

From there you can hit Ctrl+F and search for you variable. You have to know what you are looking for quite specifically though otherwise you will waste your time scrolling. I hope this answers your question. I did not find a variable called "skuId" though in the 1 level of the Ctrl + U. You sometimes have to dig deeper in the code by clicking on some of the links that lead to imported code.
I found a variable named "skuId" here. Its is in line 3097 of the link above. And it will lead you to the same place as the link below.

SHORT ANSWER:
http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/script.js?buildRev=188869&loaded=nike,jQuery,nike.ScriptLoader,nike.EventBus,nike.page.OneNikeShell,nike.page.OneNikePageLayout,nike.fonts.Selector,nike.fonts.glyphPolyfill,skin.nikestore,skin.onenike,nike.exp.global.Ad,nike.exp.global.FunctionalAndPerformance&assets=nike.exp.pdp.PdpPage,nike.gadget.BuyingOptions&assetType=SCRIPT

Comment: I am afraid then that I am not entirely sure what your goal is.

Comment: If you are in chrome and press F12 the chrome Devtool will pop up. You then click on elements and use ctrl+F. If you type skuId in the devtool searchbar you will get the chunk of code I showed above. I am just trying to find a way to get that code so that I can strip the information out using python. Hope that clears it up a bit.